# event handler results not displayed

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, user-controls

I am dynamically loading a user control. I have added an event handler which is firing and returning the correct result when debugged. However, I am filling the grid from the obtained results. Eventhough i am getting the result and the gridview is filled(as the debugging shows). But the filled gridview is not displayed instead the gridview is as it is. I don't where the error is.

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblMessage.Visible = false;
            UCAdvancedFilter.sendMessageToThePage += new AdvancedFilter.SendMessageToThePageHandler(OnsendMessageToThePage);
    }
```

Code behind

```
  protected void OnsendMessageToThePage(string id)
    {
        GroupMasterClass gm = new GroupMasterClass();
        gm.igroup_id = Convert.ToInt32(id);

         ResultClass objres = gm.fn_GetAdvancedSearchById();
         if (objres.bStatus)
         {
             eslist<GroupMasterClass> OBJLIST = objres.objData as eslist<GroupMasterClass>;
             if (OBJLIST.Count > 0)
             {
              grid.DataSource=OBJLIST;
              grid.DataBind();
             }
          }
      }
```

User control

```
public delegate void SendMessageToThePageHandler(string messageToThePage);
public event SendMessageToThePageHandler sendMessageToThePage;

#region Events


    protected void btnCloseMsg_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Panel1_ModalPopupExtender.Hide();
    }

    protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender,EventArgs e)
    {
if (sendMessageToThePage != null)
        {
            sendMessageToThePage(hdnResult.Value);
        }
}
```

On further debugging and checking I found out that the results are displayed when I click the button once more.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem with the update panel. I made the UpdateMode=Always and it started working.

Answer (score -2):

//ADD THIS CODE IN THE PARENT OR MAIN FORM 
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {

```
        LinkButton button = (LinkButton)UserControl.FindControl("btnSearch");
        //wire up event handler
        button.Click += new EventHandler(btnSearch_Click);
        UserControl.sendMessageToThePage += delegate (string message) { ButtonClick = message; };       
        base.OnInit(e);
    }
```